# Can we capture a tap event from Applicationbar on wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing a wp7 application, can we capture a tap event from Applicationbar on wp7? I have tried the below 4 ways, but they all failed.

1. Mouse event
2. Manipulation event
3. TouchPoint
4. GetureService/GestureListener

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application bar doesn't have `tap` event but you can use simple `click` event

Comment: How can I use the Click event on ApplicationBar?

Comment: well, like every other event 
`<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/iconSettings.png" Text="Settings" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_Settings" />`

                                       






`private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_Settings(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [ApplicationBar.StateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.statechanged%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event.